# Mac M1 - The Kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: macos, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, apple-m1

I have just bought a new Macbook M1, and am struggling to use Jupyter notebook in it.

These are the steps that I followed so far:

```
1. Installed Homebrew
2. Installed pyenv 
3. brew install miniforge
4. conda create -n new_env python=3.8.11
5. conda activate new_env
6. conda install Ipython
7. conda install ipykernel
8. conda install jupyter
9. pip install tensorflow
```

Then, I opened Jupyter notebook from this virtual env and tried to `import tensorflow` which gave me the error 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically'

Why does this happen? Is there anything that I missed? Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: import tensorflow in a python shell (not in jupyter), it should also crash, but the error message should be much more useful.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy This is golden advice on your part - thank you - and in my case it was the dreaded HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 that strikes again!

Answer (score 5):

There are not stable tensorflow for Apple Silicon today (2021-09-30). If you able to install via `pip install tensorflow`, then you are using conda with amd64 and translated with Rosetta 2.

Go to https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge and download Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh for arm64 version and install miniforge again.

```
bash Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

Do

```
# Delete and create your environment from scratch
conda create -n new_env python=3.8
conda activate new_env
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
conda install -c conda-forge -y pandas jupyter
```

Then you able to run tensorflow without problem.

Source: https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706

Comment: are you postdating your post!?

Comment: while installing through the command conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps it says pkg not found : tensorflow-deps.

Comment: That did not work for me unfortunately. The kernel dies even faster...

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-metal (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-metal

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430179/1117305) helped me, which refers to this [site](https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/).

1. Remove anaconda completely:

`# The following are a few examples of how you may need to delete your Anaconda folder`

`rm -rf anaconda3`

`rm -rf ~/anaconda3`

`rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3`

2. only python 3.8 is compatible, you can run in an env, and run the notebook from there.
3. miniforge3 will be instead of anaconda.